# Sharepoint list update ALL items SPServices or REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, spservices

Please tell me how to update all the elements of the list without conditions or with the condition, a separate item is updated just by ID, and all the elements of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
listName: "Library",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Manager' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query>",
batchCmd: "Update",
valuepairs: [["Manager", "Yes"]]
});
```

This answer ))

Comment: Is it possible to update a column with auto-incrementing values, prob,a single line of text - on a button click event ? i wanna generate a primarykey kind of value for my already existing list with 1200 listitems. when the list was created nobody has created a PKID . now i wanna generate  one. with unique values for all the listitems. Its not INSERT operation, its UPDATE operation.